# How to action multiple button clicks on a webpage

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

Currently pulling data from a webpage (https://www.oddschecker.com/golf/memorial-tournament/winner).

Before the data is pulled, I would like the format of the data to be decimal, as opposed to fractional. This can be done by clicking the 'wheel' in the top right of the page, followed by clicking 'decimal'.

No error is appearing within the code by VBA, however once the data is transferred across to an excel sheet, the data remains in the fractional format.

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

```vb
Sub ScrapeOdds()

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLDiv As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim InitialClick As Object
    Dim FinalClick As Object

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://www.oddschecker.com/golf/memorial-tournament/winner"

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy
    Loop

    Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
    Set HTMLDiv = HTMLDoc.getElementById("oddsTableContainer")
    Set HTMLTable = HTMLDiv.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)

    Set InitialClick = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("icon-item all-tools header-button")(0).Click
    Set FinalClick = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("OddsSettingsController as OddsSettingsController")

        For Each Obj In FinalClick

        If FinalClick.getAttribute("ng-click") = ("OddsSettingsController.setOddsType('decimal')") Then

        FinalClick.Click

        Exit For
        End If
        Next


    WriteTableToSheet HTMLTable

    IE.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: That is nested within a menu, at least for me on mobile. Isnt it easier to do the simple divisions in excel, as to convert to fractional values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click as shown below. The lines of interest for you are as follows:

```
With .document
    If .querySelectorAll(".offer-close").Length > 0 Then .querySelector(".offer-close").Click
    .querySelector(".tools-icon").Click
    If .querySelectorAll("[title='Change to decimal odds']").Length > 0 Then .querySelector("[title='Change to decimal odds']").Click
End With
```

This checks if offer pop-up ad is present and closes:

```
If .querySelectorAll(".offer-close").Length > 0 Then .querySelector(".offer-close").Click
```

This opens the wheel:

```
.querySelector(".tools-icon").Click
```

This checks if decimal is currently selected and if not selects it

```
If .querySelectorAll("[title='Change to decimal odds']").Length > 0 Then .querySelector("[title='Change to decimal odds']").Click
```

Code below removes some rubbish that is in the table at start.

---

VBA

```
Option Explicit

'VBE > Tools > References: Microsoft Internet Controls; HTML Object Library
Public Sub GetData()
    Dim ie As Object, hTable As HTMLTable, clipboard As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.oddschecker.com/golf/memorial-tournament/winner"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            If .querySelectorAll(".offer-close").Length > 0 Then .querySelector(".offer-close").Click
            .querySelector(".tools-icon").Click
            If .querySelectorAll("[title='Change to decimal odds']").Length > 0 Then .querySelector("[title='Change to decimal odds']").Click
        End With
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set hTable = .document.querySelector(".eventTable")
        clipboard.SetText hTable.outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        Dim cutOff As Range
        Set cutOff = ws.Columns(1).Find("QuickBet")
        If Not cutOff Is Nothing Then ws.rows("1:" & cutOff.Row).EntireRow.Delete
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the above - answers everything clearly and concisely. Much appreciated

Comment: Nice one QHarr!!